# How do I change the names of my keys in a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to change the key names `car` into `model` and `engine` into `fuel`. When I run my code only `value` gets changed. This is my dictionary:

```
my_dictionary = {'url': 'www.google.com', 'value': [{'car': 'Mercedes', 'engine': 'Gas'}, {'car': 'Audi', 'engine': 'Diesel'}, {'car': 'Volkswagen', 'engine': 'Hybrid'}]}
```

This is my code:

```
new_keys = ['model','fuel'] 
for key,n_key in zip(my_dictionary.keys(), new_keys):
    my_dictionary [n_key] = my_dictionary .pop(key)
```

Expected outcome:

```
my_dictionary = {'url': 'www.google.com', 'value': [{'model': 'Mercedes', 'fuel': 'Gas'}, {'model': 'Audi', 'fuel': 'Diesel'}, {'model': 'Volkswagen', 'fuel': 'Hybrid'}]}
```

PS: The second step is to transport this dictionary to MySQL do you have some tips for this? Do I need to use pandas for example?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one approach using `dict` with `zip`

**Ex:**

```
my_dictionary = {'url': 'www.google.com', 'value': [{'car': 'Mercedes', 'engine': 'Gas'}, {'car': 'Audi', 'engine': 'Diesel'}, {'car': 'Volkswagen', 'engine': 'Hybrid'}]}
new_keys = ['model','fuel'] 

my_dictionary['value'] = [dict(zip(new_keys, i.values())) for i in my_dictionary['value']]
print(my_dictionary)
```

**Output:**

```
{'url': 'www.google.com',
 'value': [{'fuel': 'Gas', 'model': 'Mercedes'},
           {'fuel': 'Diesel', 'model': 'Audi'},
           {'fuel': 'Hybrid', 'model': 'Volkswagen'}]}
```

Comment: That's a quick and good one. Thx. However, Im eager to learn why your code is working. Can you explain what you did there?

Comment: I have used `zip` to pair the keys and values --> `[('model', 'Mercedes'), ('fuel', 'Gas')]` and then used `dict` method to convert the list of tuple to a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

You're modifying the dictionary while iterating over it, which is always a recipe for trouble. One way would be to use `list(my_dictionary.keys())` to freeze the `keys()` generator into a list, but we can do better.

Also you're relying on the order in which keys appear, which (although guaranteed by recent versions of Python) is not usually well defined.

Taking those both into account:

```
key_mapping = {'car': 'model', 'engine': 'fuel'}
my_dictionary['value'] = [
    {
        key_mapping[key]: value
        for key, value in car.items()
    }
    for car in my_dictionary['value']
]
```

This is using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for the containing list, and a [dict comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) inside of that to create each inner dictionary.

Comment: Thank you but your code says: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'`

Comment: Sorry, I missed a level of nesting there. Should be better now.

Comment: Now it looks good. Thx. Now I wonder what you exactly did. You have time to to give me an explanation and the difference between yours and the answer below?

Comment: Added some links in case the syntax is unfamiliar to you. Both are fine solutions and differ mostly in style; mine is more functional whereas @Jonas's is more imperative.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
my_dictionary = {'url': 'www.google.com', 'value': [{'car': 'Mercedes', 'engine': 'Gas'}, {'car': 'Audi', 'engine': 'Diesel'}, {'car': 'Volkswagen', 'engine': 'Hybrid'}]}

for i, dictionary in enumerate(my_dictionary['value']):
    my_dictionary['value'][i]['model'] = dictionary.pop('car')
    my_dictionary['value'][i]['fuel'] = dictionary.pop('engine')
```